# MVC View to controller Passing

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am starting up with mvc and designing a simple login procedure.
I have view with login screen with two inputs username and password.
but apparently not able to get how can i pass the values of inputs from my view to controller
i am using razor. here are my snippets.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            UserName:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("userName")
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            Password
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Password("Password")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            @Html.ActionLink("login", "SignIn")
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and my controller looks like this.( i am able to redirect to controller using action link just fine.just about passing values.)

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    //string userName = Request["userName"];
    return View("Home");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enclosed above html stuff inside form container where you declared form submission method as `POST`.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            UserName:
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("userName")
        </td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            Password
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.Password("Password")
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="login" name="login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Then, you can put `Post` Action in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(FormCollection frmc)
{
    /// Extracting the value from FormCollection
    string name = frmc["userName"];
    string pwd = frmc["Password"];
    return View("Home");
}
```

Comment: perfect! that brings me to question.is that the best practice? or is there something better?

Comment: I would make the view with an `@model VmLoginParams` and make the controller post action take `public ActionResult SignIn(VmLoginParams params)` In the Html code you can then do `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)` and in the controller check for ModelState.IsValid: `if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(params)` (See also: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/188/View-Model-Design-And-Use-In-Razor-Views)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your table in Form:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "controllerName", FormMethod.POST))
{
<table>
...
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
}
```

And in controller write:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SignIn(string userName, string Password)
{
 //sign in and redirect to home page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SignIn", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        UserName:
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBox("userName")
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
        Password
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.Password("Password")
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="login" name="login" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
}
```

Model:

```
public string userName{get;set;}
public string Password{get;set;}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult SignIn(Model obj)
 {
  //sign in and redirect to home page
   string userName = obj.username;
   string password = obj.password;
 }
```

it may be help full to you.